# System.TypeInitializationException After undergrade from Entity Framework 6.2 to 5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

After changing version from Entity Framwork 6.0 to 5.0, I got this error:

> System.TypeInitializationException the type initializer for 'system.data.entity.internal.appconfig'

while starting the app.

My `web.config` file is very well ordered. I tried all solution on web but anyone worked.

Here my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
  
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
           <assemblies />
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <httpHandlers />
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
            <namespaces />
        </pages>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CCPEntities"  
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PRALGSRdb01;initial catalog=CCP;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="DefaultConnection" 
             connectionString="Data Source=PRALGSRdb01;Initial Catalog=CCP;Integrated Security=True" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="CCPEntities2" 
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PRALGSRdb01;initial catalog=CCP;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I here my line when the exception handled

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Problem Resolved After create a new project and moving all my files without touching My Web config and i reinstalled my packages manually